# Sort data in descending order of first column, for equal values, use second column in ascending order

Tags: text-processing, sort

Allow me to clarify:

Assume I have some keywords with frequency of their usage:

```
12 Hi
7  Hash
7  C++  
9  Superuser
17 Stackoverflow
9  LaTeX  
42 Life
9  Ubuntu
```

What I want, is to sort this data based on frequency in descending order and if there are some equal values, it should use the second column in ascending order.

```
sort -n -r foo.txt
```

Does the first part but then second column are also `reversed`:

```
42 Life
17 Stackoverflow
12 Hi
9  Ubuntu
9  Superuser
9  LaTeX  
7  Hash
7  C++
```

How can I achieve the following results?

```
42 Life
17 Stackoverflow
12 Hi
9  LaTeX  
9  Superuser
9  Ubuntu
7  C++ 
7  Hash
```

I think I have to use `-k` argument but I can't figure out how!

I want to know how this can be done using solely `sort` command of `bash`. However if it's not possible to achieve this only by `sort`, other commands should be Bourne shell compatible.

Comment: [Somewhat OT]: although equivalent for this particular-data, using GNU-sort `-g` (general numeric) option instead of `-n` for numerical comparisons is safer: it works correctly for both floating point and integers.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Specify the sort keys separately with the criteria:

```
sort -k1,1nr -k2,2 inputfile
```

This specifies that the first key is sorted numerically in reverse order while the second is sorted as per the *default* sort order.

Quoting from [POSIX sort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html):

> **-k**  *keydef*
>
> The *keydef* argument is a restricted sort key field definition. The format of this definition is:
>
> *field_start***[***type***][***,field_end***[***type***]]**
>
> where *field_start* and *field_end* define a key field restricted to a portion of the line (see the EXTENDED DESCRIPTION section), and type
>   is a modifier from the list of characters 'b', 'd', 'f', 'i', 'n',
>   'r'. The 'b' modifier shall behave like the `-b` option, but shall apply
>   only to the *field_start* or *field_end* to which it is attached. The
>   other modifiers shall behave like the corresponding options, but shall
>   apply only to the key field to which they are attached; they shall
>   have this effect if specified with *field_start*, *field_end*, or both. If
>   any modifier is attached to a *field_start* or to a *field_end*, no option
>   shall apply to either. Implementations shall support at least nine
>   occurrences of the `-k` option, which shall be significant in command
>   line order. If no `-k` option is specified, a default sort key of the
>   entire line shall be used.
>
> When there are multiple key fields, later keys shall be compared only after all earlier keys compare equal. Except when the `-u` option
>   is specified, lines that otherwise compare equal shall be ordered as
>   if none of the options `-d`, `-f`, `-i`, `-n`, or `-k` were present (but with `-r`
>   still in effect, if it was specified) and with all bytes in the lines
>   significant to the comparison. The order in which lines that still
>   compare equal are written is unspecified.

This would produce:

```
42 Life
17 Stackoverflow
12 Hi
9  LaTeX
9  Superuser
9  Ubuntu
7  C++
7  Hash
```

Comment: Thanks. Did the trick. Have to wait 10 minutes to accept!

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for pointing it out; updated the reference.